# Black hole expiration dates

Tags: black-holes, hawking-radiation

According to this answer: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/150020/36709

Very "light" black holes have a life expectancy in the range of $10^{18}$ years while very "heavy" black holes have a life expectancy between $10^{12}$ or so years.

- Stephen Hawkings book Black Holes and Baby Universes.

How heavy would a black hole have to be to have a life expectancy, so that it could have ended life within the time frame of our universe?

What is the relationship between life expectancy of a black hole and its mass?

Comment: 1. "According to a comment on this site" is a pretty useless reference. Give the link! 2. Is this comment meant to hold in classical GR or in the semi-classical picture where black holes radiate Hawking radiation?

Comment: There is no way that is correct - the evaporation time increases with the cube of the mass, cf. e.g. the (crude) analysis in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_radiation#A_crude_analytic_estimate). Moreover, for black holes bigger than the mass of the Moon, the Hawking radiation temperature is cooler than the CMB, so any evaporation is cancelled out by CMB photons going in.

Comment: 0. It was just a mistake

Comment: This is basically an exercise in doing some math from the equations Wikipedia gives (see the link in Emilio's post).

Comment: @ACuriousMind I've added a link to the question.

Answer (score 1):

The time for a black hole with mass M to evaporate is proportional to M^3.

Here is a detailed description:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_radiation#Black_hole_evaporation